# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in SiteController#create Rails inserting null values for all the fields

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to RoR and I am having some problems implementing a rails application for an existing database. The last one I cannot get rid of and I cannot find nothing about this in the web as well so I decided to post it here. Thank you in advance!

The Error:

When I try to insert a new register to the site table, I receive this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in SiteController#create

Mysql2::Error: Column 'idcustomer' cannot be null: INSERT INTO `site` (`name`, `address`, `postcode`, `idcustomer`, `observations`) VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)

Rails.root: /Users/biali/rails/gtonline

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace app/controllers/site_controller.rb:37:in `block in create' app/controllers/site_controller.rb:36:in `create'
```

Request

Parameters:

```
 {"utf8"=>"âœ“", 
 "authenticity_token"=>"5Yzo/fIZ7SnRuEHHep6bpuQsRcwl0goLLDg=",
 "site"=>{"name"=>"1321231", 
 "address"=>"32131", 
 "postcode"=>"321231", 
 "observations"=>"321321321"}, 
 "idcustomer"=>"64",  "commit"=>"Create
 Site",  "belongs_to"=>:customer}
```

The Table:

```
mysql> desc site;
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| idsite       | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name         | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| address      | text        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| postcode     | varchar(8)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| idcustomer   | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| observations | text        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

The Model:

```
class Site < ActiveRecord::Base
    set_table_name 'site'
    set_primary_key 'idsite'    

    belongs_to :customer, :foreign_key=>'idcustomer'
end
```

The Controller:

```
...

  def new
    @site = Site.new 

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.xml { render :xml => @site }
    end
  end

  def create
    @site = Site.new(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
        if @site.save
            format.html { redirect_to(@site, :notice => 'Site was successfully added.') }
            format.xml  { render :xml => @site, :status => :created, :location => @site }
        else
            format.html { render :action => "new" }
            format.xml  { render :xml => @site.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
        end
    end
  end

...
```

The View:

```
<h1>New Site</h1>
<%= render 'form' %>
<%= link_to 'Back', sites_path %>


_form:

<%= form_for(@site) do |f| %>
  <% if @site.errors.any? %>
  <div id="errorExplanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@site.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this insertion from being saved:</h2>
    <ul>
    <% @site.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :address %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :address %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :postcode %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :postcode %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :observations %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :observations %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    Customer<br />
    <%= select_tag(:idcustomer, options_for_select(Customer.order('name').map {|customer| [customer.name, customer.idcustomer]}, @idcustomer)) %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= select_tag(:idcustomer, options_for_select(Customer.order('name').map {|customer| [customer.name, customer.idcustomer]}, @idcustomer)) %>
```

should be something like:

```
<%= f.select :idcustomer, options_for_select(Customer.order('name').map{|customer| [customer.name, customer.idcustomer]}, @idcustomer) %>
```

or

```
<%= select_tag('site[idcustomer]', options_for_select(Customer.order('name').map {|customer| [customer.name, customer.idcustomer]}, @idcustomer)) %>
```